# Can't insert button as "on top"

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulties positioning this selfmade Button on top of the Lightbox (Upper right). Whatever I do with the `z-index`, it stays inside the Box.

Here the [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqx7b3n4/2/) to play with. CSS Panel might be a bit long (166 lines).

So..what am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` only put element on the top of "visibility" or "overlaying", your problem is, that parent of your button dont allow to show anything outside that div with `overflow:auto` it create scrollbar instead. If you want to show something outside this div, put it outside your div, or allow elements to be rendered outside parent with `overflow:visible` :

```
.white_content {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

the first way is maybe better for you

Comment: Oh....that makes actually sense. I get it. I'll try some stuff and if everything works I'll post it. Thanks.

Comment: Well. It did work, everything worked out just fine, with one slight problem. We set the outflow to visible, so everything will go over the div once it gets resized by Browser. And I only want to have the Button as visible, and the rest of the div auto. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, you can additionaly wrap your whole content(exclude your button) to div with :`position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:auto;`

Comment: Can you show me that please, by using the JSFIDDLE? I'm unsure on how to exclude the button from the `div.white_content`. Because it's already set to 25% or 50%. (I've added some content to the JSFIDDLE link for you to start fiddling around.) Thanks!

Comment: Don't know how to thank you properly. But thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

```
.class
{
position:relative;
top:20%;
}
```

Comment: Try like it.You should adjust the top % according to your requirement.

Comment: I need the Button to be on top of everything shown if lightbox on. Like a sticker put on the edge of the Lightbox. I wanted to move it higher on the layer. But as I said it doesn't really work for me. Or am I misunderstanding by what you ment?